# Why is my jekyll posts page giving a 404 error after I attempted to add seo tags into the site templates?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I tried to follow the instructions here and add seo tags into the site templates and the config.yaml and gemfiles but it led to me getting a 404 error message when attempting to view my posts page. 
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/installation.md

here is my site url and the posts url can anyone help? Thanks.
http://www.nezmustafa.com/
http://www.nezmustafa.com//posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've configured a custom domain on your repo and url is no longer "*nezmustafa123.github.io/blog/*"

In ***_config.yml***, set :

```
url: "http://www.nezmustafa.com"
baseurl: ""
```

Comment: I changed it but it ended up breaking the css a bit I think
http://www.nezmustafa.com/